# How can I change the color of "Camera Roll" in the UIImagePickerController?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Here is an image of what I mean. I just want the title of "Camera Roll" to be white like the status bar.

#### Screen shot of UIImagePickerController

[image: Screen shot of UIImagePickerController]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the navigation bar title color before presenting the `UIImagePickerController`

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
```